# Probability and expectation for the sampling of poison bugs

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> In a certain country, a species of bugs are consumed where a probability $x$ of bugs cause nausea. The chemical that causes nausea is potent enough to induce symptoms regardless of how diluted it is with the protein of regular bugs $(1-x)$. Given $N=pq$, the following protocol is used to determine which bugs cause nausea.
>
> The bugs are divided into $q$ groups of $p$ bugs. For each group of bugs, a sample of the protein of all $p$ bugs in the group are extracted and sampled. If no nausea is induced, none of the bugs in the group are poisonous. If nausea is induced, all the $p$ bugs are sampled individually to find which bug/bugs are poisonous.
>
> a) What is the probability that a mixture has a poisonous bug?
>
> b) What is the expected number of tests (both group and individual)?

Where I am right now:

a) We know that there is a probability of $x$ for a poisonous bug. The probability that a mixture has a poisonous bug would depend on the number of bugs in each group. The chance of getting a group of completely non-poisonous bugs would be $(1-x)^p$. Then we subtract that from a total probability of $1$, getting $1-(1-x)^p$.

b) This is where I am at the most loss for tackling the problem. The chance of a mixture not having a poisonous bug would be $(1-x)^p$. That is the probability that a group will only have to be sampled once, and we can multiply that by $q$ to get an initial number of samples that only need to be sampled once. Now when a group has to be sampled again to find the poisonous bug,we should take the following route: Number of groups that only have to be sampled once are $q(1-x)^p$. We add this to the number of groups that need to be sampled multiple times: $q(1-(1-x)^p)(1+p)$.

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  what does "otherwise, all the $p$ bugs are sampled individually" mean?  the problem suggests that there is both a group and an individual procedure...I guess you can test all $p$ pugs at once.  But if poison were detected you would know at least one bug was poisoned, so what else would you need to test for?  Also:  what have you tried here?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I see the edit...so the point is to identify all the poisonous bugs.  And the group test lets you skip the individual test if you are lucky enough to have a clean sample.  Fine.  So, what have you tried?  You tell us that each bug is toxic with probability $x$.  Presumably you assume the bugs are independent.  So...what is the probability that two bugs are both clean?  How about three bugs?

Comment: Provided more explanation of where I am right now.

Comment: Good!  So, let's just look at one group of $p$ bugs.  What is the expected number of tests you need to do on that group?  Hint:  Either you have to do $1$ test or you have to do $p+1$.

Comment: After that:  remember that expected value is linear.  If you knew that the expected number for a single group was $E$ then the total answer is $qE$.

Comment: Okay, I definitely my answer to (a) is more solid after thinking about it some more (probability would not be just x). Would it be possible to apply that answer for part B? I am at a loss for calculating E for one group since p is not defined and we do not know x,, though I do see how the linearity of expectations can be applied. How do we go about calculating E?

Comment: Well, stick to one group.  you have to do $1$ test with probability $(1-x)^p$.  Otherwise, you need to do $p+1$.  Thus $E=(1-x)^p\times 1+\left(1-(1-x)^p\right)\times (p+1)$.  That's it!  As you say, not knowing $x$ there's not much  more you can say about that.  Well, you can simplify the expression somewhat.

Comment: Ah, okay! And then you multiply all that by q! Thanks for helping me a ton for thinking through this. :)

Comment: No problem at all.